# Is there a math expression for the sum of all items in a set?

Tags: summation, notation

I'm looking for a math symbol that represents the sum of all items in a set. Is there such a symbol?

For example, $x = \{2,8,3\}$
The sum of $x = 2 + 8 + 3 = 13$

Example with $\#$ meaning the sum of a set's items, $\#x = 13$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: May I ask what you meant by adding the tag [(numerical-methods)](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/numerical-methods/info)?

Comment: I had no idea where this should go. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X = \{ 2,8,3\}$, then $$\sum_{i \in X} i = 13$$